# How to do += in TCL

Tags: math, tcl

```
set windowSize 0

for {set i 0} {$i < 14} {incr i} {
  set $windowSize [expr $windowSize + [$tcp($i) set cwnd_]]
}
puts "$windowSize"
```

This prints out zero, when the values being added are non zero. How to do this without a temp var? Holla if you love TCL. ...dead silence.

Comment: While it's understandable to make a mistake about how variables are referenced in Tcl if you come from a language that always prefixed their names with $s... it's somewhat bad form to make snippy comments about the language being bad when it was your own misunderstanding it's extremely simple syntax that led to the problem.

Comment: it was a joke. why so serious?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`set $windowSize` substitutes the value of `$windowSize` before running the command.

You want `set windowSize [expr ...]`, or even simpler:

```
incr windowSize [$tcp($i) set cwnd_]
```

Comment: Sometimes the item being added is zero, in which case there is the error message "expected integer, got 0.0" What to do. what to do?

Comment: incr requires an integer, so if you need to handle floats, use the longer form. http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/incr.htm